# Loading PubNub with Require.js

Tags: requirejs, pubnub

I am attempting to load PubNub into my project with Require.  But "PubNub" is returning as undefined when I try to initialize it.

I have downloaded the current pubnub.4.20.1.js and have included it in the scripts folder of my project.  Here is my Require code:

```
require.config({
paths: {
    jquery: '../../jquery-2.2.3.min',
    bootstrap: '../../bootstrap.min',
    underscore: '../../underscore.min',
    backbone: '../../backbone.min',
    marionette: '../../backbone.marionette.min',
    handlebars: '../../handlebars.min',
    pubnub: '../../pubnub.4.20.1'
},

shim: {
    underscore: {
        exports: '_'
    },

    backbone: {
        deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
        exports: "Backbone"
    },

    marionette: {
        deps: ["backbone"],
        exports: "Marionette"
    },

    pubnub: {
        exports: "PubNub"
    }
}});

require(
["marionette",
"handlebars", 
"bootstrap",
"pubnub"], function (Marionette, PubNub) {
    window.App = new Marionette.Application();

    // Initialize Pubnub
    App.pubnub = PubNub.init({
        publish_key: 'pub-c-0d5593f5-bf33-4d4a-b3a7-70a941b2282b',
        subscribe_key: 'sub-c-e4b4d296-1bd4-11e8-a9da-22fca5d72012'
    });
);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: I'm not receiving an error message sadly.  There's nothing in the console.  If I stop the code at the line that pushes Marionette and PubNub into the function, Marionette has its standard definitions, but PubNub comes up Undefined.

Comment: `PubNub` api is not good. Use `twilio`. It is better.

Answer (score 2):

## PubNub and Require JS

> **Update: See [Louis's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49040241/524733) answer on this page.**
>
> PubNub SDK is WebPacked.  You have to do extra steps to make it work with RequireJS.  See answer from [@Louis PubNub and Require JS on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49040241/524733).

- **Problem**: Webpack won't bundle files with requireJS/AMD syntax in them.
- **Question**: Is there any way to make webpack play nice with requireJS?
- **Answer**: See answer from Louis https://stackoverflow.com/a/49040241/524733

RequireJS and Webpack **will** automatically play together nicely.  And in this case the original question posted by @SingingSmitty shows that usage of `shim` was erroneous.  According to Louis:

> You should use `shim` only for code that does not register itself as a proper AMD module. Code that calls define registers itself as a proper AMD module, so you don't use shim for such code. You should remove the shim for PubNub because it calls define (look in the source code, at the start of the file). Unless you are using antiquated versions of Underscore, Backbone and Marionette, you should also remove the shim entries for them because they are proper AMD modules.  [Read full answer from Louis on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49040241/524733).
>
> In the problem provided by the OP ( @SingingSmitty ), they do in fact play well together. The OP went and did something they should not have done: defining erroneous shim. The usage of shim is entirely orthogonal to whether Webpack is involved. Webpack can produce bundles that require shim and can produce bundles that don't. Moreover, whether to use shim or not is entirely independent on whether Webpack is part of the toolchain that produced the bundle.

This blog post describes the journey http://devalias.net/devalias/2017/08/05/unexpected-journey-webpack-requirejs/ using Webpack and RequireJS.

Few more links below.

https://gist.github.com/xjamundx/b1c800e9282e16a6a18e
https://www.npmjs.com/package/requirejs-to-webpack-cli

Comment: "Webpack won't bundle files with requireJS/AMD syntax in them." Generally speaking, that's untrue. Webpack is able of consuming AMD modules. (See [this](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/modules/#what-is-a-webpack-module)). "RequireJS and Webpack don't play together." Again, untrue as a general statement. It is *possible* to create a project that works with RequireJS but not with Webpack. But because *some* projects are problematic, it does not follow that *all* projects are doomed. I have a large project consisting of AMD modules. Webpack consumes it quite happily and produces a fine bundle.

Comment: "RequireJS and Webpack don't automatically play together." In general, they do automatically play well together. In the problem provided by the OP, they do in fact play well together. The OP went and did something they should not have done: defining erroneous `shim`. The usage of `shim` is *entirely orthogonal* to whether Webpack is involved. Webpack can produce bundles that require `shim` and can produce bundles that don't. Moreover, whether to use `shim` or not is entirely independent on whether Webpack is part of the toolchain that produced the bundle.

Comment: @Louis Nice!  Updating post a bit to match your description.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used PubNub but was able to get it to work with RequireJS in about 5 minutes. [Here is a plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/1qINTGiE4wsY4qm5fE5D?p=preview) containing the "hello world" example given in the [PubNub documentation](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk#hello_world). I've just added the necessary code to load RequireJS and PubNub and called `publish()` and it just worked.

Here are issues I see with the code you show:

1. `PubNub.init` does not exist. So even if it loads properly, you're going to have an error.
2. You are using `shim` incorrectly. You should use it only for code that does not register itself as a proper AMD module. Code that calls `define` registers itself as a proper AMD module, so you don't use `shim` for such code. You should remove the `shim` for PubNub because it calls `define` (look in the source code, at the start of the file). Unless you are using antiquated versions of Underscore, Backbone and Marionette, you should also remove the `shim` entries for them because they are proper AMD modules.

I'm copying here the `script` elements from the plunk:

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.5/require.js">
  </script>
  <script>
    require.config({
      paths: {
        pubnub: "https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.20.1",
      }
    });

    require(["pubnub"], function(PubNub) {
      console.log(PubNub);

      function publish() {

        pubnub = new PubNub({
          publishKey: 'demo',
          subscribeKey: 'demo'
        })

        function publishSampleMessage() {
          console.log("Since we're publishing on subscribe connectEvent, we're sure we'll receive the following publish.");
          var publishConfig = {
            channel: "hello_world",
            message: "Hello from PubNub Docs!"
          }
          pubnub.publish(publishConfig, function(status, response) {
            console.log(status, response);
          })
        }

        pubnub.addListener({
          status: function(statusEvent) {
            if (statusEvent.category === "PNConnectedCategory") {
              publishSampleMessage();
            }
          },
          message: function(message) {
            console.log("New Message!!", message);
          },
          presence: function(presenceEvent) {
            // handle presence
          }
        })
        console.log("Subscribing..");
        pubnub.subscribe({
          channels: ['hello_world']
        });
      }

      publish();
    })
  </script>
```

Comment: We've updated our original answer. We reference your answer as the **best**.